# How to obfuscate data using during modeling

Tags: regression, modeling, spatial

I have a situation where I need to model the relationship between field plot data and satellite imagery data. However, these field plot locations are hidden and I cannot learn their true locations. The researchers who have the data are reluctant to share the data if I have a way of figuring out where the plots are located. I want to model the relationship between the plots and the images and then expand the model over the rest of the data to create a map.

Here is an example of what I am describing:

The plot data contains an ID and the response for the model:

```
+------------+------------+
|    Plot    |  response  |
+------------+------------+
| plot 1     |    123     |
| plot 2     |    173     |
| plot 3     |    142     |
+------------+------------+
```

Next, the X, Y coordinates of the plots are used to extract covariates from pixels in a satellite image. I can then do my modeling without needing spatial dataset for the plot locations:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|    Plot    |  response  | variable 1 | variable 1 | variable 1 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| plot 1     |    123     |   .4324    |   .94932   |   .21232   |
| plot 2     |    173     |   .2354    |   .87342   |   .43234   |
| plot 3     |    142     |   .0878    |   .78989   |   .34323   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

However, the problem is that once I have the response variables, I can easily just work backwards to get the plot locations (i.e. just look up the pixel with the values .4324, .94932, and .21232).

Here is my question: is there a technique by which I could somehow my data and such that I could create valid models but not be able to work out the plot locations?

I played around with the idea of raising all of my covariates to a prime of their choosing. That way, I can't work back to a given pixel value but I could still create a valid model. However, mathematically, that obviously don't work and I don't get coefficents I can use with my data.

The key is that I can then use the final model with my original data to produce maps. The method doesn't need to be impervious but generally strong enough that your average Joe/Jane couldn't work backwards.

Comment: Your possibilities are determined by the model (specifically, what transformations will have no meaningful effect on the results) and the nature of the data (such as their degree of spatial correlation, any natural limits, sizes of the plots, resolutions of the images, inherent accuracy and precision of the images, and so on).  By disclosing as much of that information as you can, you will increase your chance of getting good, focused answers.

Comment: I'm not yet sure of the total size of satellite image dataset (300,00,000 30 meter pixels is a reasonable guess). However, the model will be trained using ~3000-4000 plot locations which cover roughly 13m^2 . Spatial correlation among the variables is expected as we are dealing with natural environments and they tend to get correlated over ecological gradients. The plan for modeling was first experiment with using random forests as it tends to perform better than parametric techniques for satellite data. Plot location inaccuracies have been negligible in previous modeling exercises.